# Show that the system of differential equation has no non-trivial solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system of differential equation with constant coefficients

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=a_1x+b_1y$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=a_2x+b_2y$$

Assume the roots of the characteristic equations are real and equal.

Assume that the system is not such $a_1=b_2\neq 0 $ and $ a_2=b_1=0 $.

Show that there exists no non-trivial solution of the form

$$x=Ate^{\lambda t}$$

$$y=Bte^{\lambda t}$$

which is linearly independent of the solution

$$x=Ae^{\lambda t}$$

$$y=Be^{\lambda t}$$

My work:

I try to differentiate and substitute into the differential equation,

Find out the determinant which is very messy.

I am not sure how to show this? Any simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$(Ate^{\lambda t})'=Ae^{\lambda t}+At\lambda e^{\lambda t}$$ must be equal to $$a_1x+b_1y=(a_1A+b_1B)te^{\lambda t},$$ we find that $A=0$ (note that $e^{\lambda t}$ and $te^{\lambda t}$ are linearly independent).
Similarly, you get $B=0$ substituting in the other equation. So there exist no nontrivial solution of that form.

Comment: It is not necessary to find the determinant?

Comment: No, but do you understand the argument?

Comment: Yes. I understand it. We must have A=B=0 if the above is true

Comment: Indeed, so nothing else is needed, not even the conditions on the constants.